# Elm: let binding and type annotations with tuples

Tags: elm

How would I apply type annotations for the code snippet below? Note: e and r are List Tree's.

```
let
  {--what is the type annotation here for the tuple (e, r)?--}
  ( e, r ) = List.partition (\(Node a _) -> a == (toString c)) lt
in....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there is a destructuring statement, and cannot have a type annotation.

Type annotations are for named functions or values. For example:

```
plus : Int -> Int -> Int
plus = (+)

year : Int
year = 2017
```

Your destructuring of `(e, r)` is not a named function. It merely introduces two new values to the scope, `e` and `r`.

Comment: So if we use pattern matching(in let binding) to destruct something then type annotations are unavailable. OK. Thanks.